# Что делать, если glFrustum ничего не делает?

Tags: c, winapi, opengl

glFrustum, как я понял, должен делать проекцию перспективной, но когда я его вызываю, проекция остаётся оргографической. Видимые объекты при увеличении координаты по оси z не уменьшаются, а остаются своего размера, то есть glFrustum ничего не делает. Как это исправить?

Код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC*, HGLRC*);
void DisableOpenGL(HWND, HDC, HGLRC);

float vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
};


int main() {
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;

    /* register window class */
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = NULL;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"GLSample";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    HWND dw = GetDesktopWindow();
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(dw, &rect);


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    /* create main window */
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        L"GLSample",
        L"OpenGL Sample",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        rect.right,
        rect.bottom,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);

    /* enable OpenGL for the window */
    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    /* program main loop */
    while (!bQuit)
    {
        /* check for messages */
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            /* handle or dispatch messages */
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* OpenGL animation code goes here */

            glFrustum(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -2.0f, 600000000.0f);

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices);
            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.01f);

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));

            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

            SwapBuffers(hDC);

            Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    /* shutdown OpenGL */
    DisableOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);

    /* destroy the window explicitly */
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        return 0;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    /* get the device context (DC) */
    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    /* set the pixel format for the DC */
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    /* create and enable the render context (RC) */
    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}

void DisableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}
```

Comment: `glFrustum` умножает последнюю матрицу в заданной стопке матриц на создаваемую матрицу с перспективной проекцией. У вас в стопке матриц пусто, хотя по идее предварительно следует выбрать `GL_PROJECTION ` и загрузить туда матрицу эквивалентности `glLoadIdentity`. Ну а вообще это все устаревшие функции, не тратьте на них свое время.

Comment: @user7860670 А какие функции лучше использовать вместо этих, если они устарели?

Comment: Переходите на современный OpenGL с шейдерами.

Answer (score 0):

Не работает, потому что параметр `near` должен быть больше нуля, а у вас он **-2**.

Попробуйте так:

```
glFrustum(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.01f, 1000.0f);
```